# exception while adding multiple rows to datatable. Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRowCollection>

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, datatable

`idLocals` is Primary key in database

Populating the datatable

```
oDtLocalCharge = bll.GetData();
```

i am copying the datatable in another function

```
   dtLocalCharges = oDtLocalCharge.Copy();
```

---

and trying to add rows using below code

```
DataRowCollection drr = oDtLocalCharge.Rows;
dtLocalCharges.Rows.Add(drr);
```

When i try to add rows to datatable, i am getting error as below

---

```
Error: 
{System.ArgumentException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRowCollection> in idLocals Column.  Expected type is Int32. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

May be Primary Key `idLocals`is causing problem
what is the problem?

How can i fix this? I want to multiple add rows in `dtLocalCharges` table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can't use Add() with a DataRowCollection. You need to add each row individually. You will probably need to use NewRow, copy the values and then call Add.

Try this first:

```
DataRowCollection drr = oDtLocalCharge.Rows;
foreach (var row in drr) dtLocalCharges.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Good one! I didn't look at the entire DataTable API.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to import all rows of one datatable into another datatable:

```
datatable1.Load(New DataTableReader(datatable2))
```